# What's the usage of rbash?

Tags: bash, shell, restricted-shell

I've read some questions about the difference of TTY, console, terminal, etc here and on Askubuntu.

Someone mentioned restricted shell, like `rbash` or `bash -r`. 
I first fought it is good to give someone very restricted access to a computer, but it is very easy to break out. Just start `bash`.

So what's the usage of rbash, when you can break out so easily or are other shells more secure (`sh -r`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restricted shells like rbash need careful setup; eg setting a PATH variable that points to a directory (e.g. /usr/local/rbin) that only has the commands you want to let people run.  Make sure the user can't modify their home directory so they can't change startup scripts.  At that point the user is limited.

If you allow the standard /bin and /usr/bin directories to be on the user PATH then, as you've found out, people can easily escape the restrictions.